# How to stop woocommerce from send email to admin for free order?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Currently, In my wordpress + woocommerce systems has free product for customer.

Customer frequently buy these free product and woocommerce send out the email to admin every order they buy free product.

I try to find the way to stop woocommerce from sending email to admin when customer buy free product only ( Total Amount = 0 ).

But I could not find the way.

Answer (score 0):

This should stop sending the **new order** e-mails to the admin if the total order amount is 0.00. You can place this in the functions.php of your theme:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_enabled_new_order', function($enabled, $order) {

    if ($order instanceof WC_Order) {

        $order_total = floatval($order->get_total());

        if ($order_total == 0) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    return $enabled;

}, 10, 2);
```